# Grammar for java like switch case function using ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I would like to implement java like switch-case functionality using ANTLR.

Following is the grammar I defined:

```
switchFunction
: "switch"^ LPAREN ! expression RPAREN ! LCURLY ! ( caseFuntion )* RCURLY !
;

caseFunction
: ("case"^ expression | "default") COLON!
;
```

But when I give the following example language, I am getting error saying RCURLY is expected but found print

```
switch(fruit)
{
  case 'Apple': print "apple";
}
```

Can someone help me with the grammar for switch case

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not giving more details. I updated my example and error i received above. Yes I am using ANTLR V2 version.

Answer (score 1):

You have forget to define what comes after the COLON.

```
("case"^ expression | "default") COLON!
```

matches to

```
case 'Apple':
```

but you have nothing for

```
print "apple";
```

You need something like this (I don't know ANTLR 2 good, don't take it literally!):

```
("case"^ expression | "default") COLON! statement
```